# Design pattern options for different parameter types for the same logic

Tags: design-patterns

I have two methods as below:
    AddSingleEmployee(Employee e);
    AddMultipleEmployees(List e);

The logic implemented in both these methods are same, only difference is the object type. If it is multiple employees, I am using a foreach loop to populate the Employee properties, otherwise not.

Is there any pattern that can be used to implement this? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

There are no patterns for such simple thing - simply call first method in a loop from second method. C# sample:

```
public void AddMultipleEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
{
    foreach(Employee employee in employees)
       AddSingleEmployee(employee);
}
```

Also there is no need to specify parameter type in method name - you can use method overloading in such languages as C# or Java:

```
public void Add(List<Employee> employees)
{
    foreach(Employee employee in employees)
       Add(employee);
}

public void Add(Employee employees)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change it from accepting a list to an array then you can refactor it into one method:

```
public void addEmployee(Employee... employees) {
   for (Employee e : Arrays.asList(employees)) {
       // TODO
   }
}
```

This method will accept one or more employees and makes it easier for the caller to reason about.